# Firebase otp is not showing up

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Firebase is sending the verification id but not the actual otp. I have setup all the necessary enviornment but still otp does not come but verification id is available and the oncodesent callback is triggered only thing is otp doesnot arrive. Does anybody know the reason for it?
(Tried: removing whitelisting of number, enabling phone auth, not exceeding the quotas, added sha keys). This problem is occuring nowadays. Somedays before everything was perfect.